# Heroku : 404 (Not Found), "dist/" not created

Tags: reactjs, nginx, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to understand how PWA works and so I want to deploy my React PWA on Heroku. After a successful deployment with no error, when I'm visiting my web app page I have this white page with: **404 Not Found nginx**

After some research I figured out, I need to use this **buildpack**: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static

I've created a **static.json** config file :

```
{
  "root": "dist/",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

I've added (like explained there: [https://gist.github.com/hone/24b06869b4c1eca701f9](http://Getting%20Started%20Heroku)) these 2 **buildpacks**:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/hone/heroku-buildpack-static
```

But it still not working. *I still have 404 not found when I visit my page.*

I can't find a clear error message in the logs, here my **heroku logs** after a deployment:

```
2017-08-24T08:40:15.818194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-08-24T08:40:15.819113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-08-24T08:40:15.520597+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user me@gmail.com
2017-08-24T08:40:16.760078+00:00 app[web.1]: Going down, terminating child processes...
2017-08-24T08:40:16.742709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-08-24T08:40:16.852882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-08-24T08:40:18.004409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/boot`
2017-08-24T08:40:21.135817+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting log redirection...
2017-08-24T08:40:21.136153+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx...
2017-08-24T08:40:21.778827+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-08-24T08:40:36.136610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=my-host.herokuapp.com request_id=5056fc07-1c22-4a91-ba91-c662a1c70dfa fwd="217.169.5.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=403 protocol=https
2017-08-24T08:40:36.138603+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.157.112.148 - - [24/Aug/2017:08:40:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 191 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
```

Here my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "description": "mydescription",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "webpack --env.production --config ./config/webpack.js --progress",
    "build": "webpack --env.production --config config/webpack",
    "start": "serve dist -s",
    "watch": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "ganalytics": "^2.0.1",
    "md-colors": "^1.0.0",
    "preact": "^8.2.1",
    "preact-router": "^2.5.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-babili": "^0.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.15",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "serve": "^6.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.4",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

My **app structure** is :

[image]

Finally the **manifest** file:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "short_name": "shorname",
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=homescreen",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#F2F2F2",
  "theme_color": "#c10079",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "icon/android-chrome-192x192.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  }, {
    "src": "icon/android-chrome-512x512.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }]
}
```

I'm wondering if it's not because of the dist folder. When I run heroku run bash, I can't see any dist folder so maybe there is a build problem around that? In dist folder I have the index.html which should be available so then it might explains why I have a not found 404 error..

**Update:**
So I removed the dist folder from my .gitignore and in my static.json I have now root: "./dist". And now it's working. I'm no sure why Heroku doesn't generate my dist file.

**Update 2:** 
I'm trying to work with postinstall in my package.json :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up
So far I still have the same issue even with:
"postinstall": "npm install && npm run build" in the scripts part of the package.json

**Update 3:**
Problem fixed ! I've added NodeJS buildpack: heroku/nodejs
and now it's working. I'm using for my package json script : "postinstall": "webpack --env.production --config ./config/webpack.js --progress", and my NODE_ENV=production and NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true

Comment: Have you tried with a `heroku-postbuild` script in your package.json? I'm running several apps on heroku that uses that to build themselves. Also make sure the required dependencies are installed, heroku runs with NODE_ENV production so devDependencies will be ignored by default.

Comment: @ivarni thanks, that's good to know it's working for you, so I can keep looking for a solution with heroku-postbuild. I've tried with it but it's still, not working, I must have definitely missed something for sure.
"heroku-postbuild": "webpack -p --config ./config/webpack.js --progress"